# Run Android apk in Device without User interaction

Tags: android, apk

I need to know how it is possible - After installing apk in my device via adb command, I want to run the app automatically. No user interaction will be used to run and navigate screens. The installed app will be run and navigate from one screen to another automatically. But all screen should be reached. I don't know how it is possible?

Let me share an example. Say, my app has SignIn and SignUp features. After installing the apk in device, I want the app will execute SignIn or SignUp code automatically, without user interaction.

The Actual steps are:

1. APK will be installed via adb command.
2. After installing apk, app should be run in device automatically, without any user interaction.
3. As app will be run without user interaction, I need to know how much time app is taking to SignIn, SignUp or Other screen redering. Right now, focusing SignIn and SignUp time. After getting time (it is easy find out how much time it needs to SignIn) app will send the time in server (via PHP and it is easy to do).

Any Idea from Experts?

Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what do you expect the app to do basically?

Comment: And, if your objective is to have the user not use these activities, why did you write them in the first place?

Comment: My main goal is, I like to test the app without any user interaction. So, after installing the apk in device, I need to know how much time app taking to SignIn or SignUp. And here I want no User interaction.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Comment: Everyone please note the mention of ADB - this is obviously a special/test case, and so things are possible for which there would not be the necessary permission when a secured device runs standalone.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks!, Seems interesting. Let me explore, then I can understand it will surve my purpose or not.

Comment: @Simon: I have seen MonkeyRunner, it is really good. But do you have any more idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MonkeyRunner (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) is a good solution. Though it can't serve all things what I need, but I did not find any solution for my requirement. Thanks @Simon for introducing MonkeyRunner.

Answer (score -2):

**MonkeyRunner** script should meet your requirement or **Robotium** ?

Comment: Robotium is NOT what I am looking.